# Neo4j Batch import using java

Tags: java, neo4j

I need to do a batch import of data into Neo 4j using java api Can any one help me with some sample code

Answer (score 1):

Amrutha have you seen the documentation about the [batch inserter](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html) which has code samples?

There's also a page on importing data into Neo4j which describes more options: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import

Comment: I have seen this bug unable to figure out the mapping of the class.Any help on that

Comment: You'll have to provide more information if it's a specific issue you are facing- please update your question with details, thanks

Comment: I want to load a csv file into neo4j using java

Comment: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html

Comment: You can still run Cypher. Otherwise take a look at the batch inserter that I referenced earlier

Comment: Do you have a sample example using  Transactional HTTP endpoint